# Run Druid as a background service

Tags: java, linux, service, druid

I've setup Druid on an AWS `r3.large` instance and configured all the required nodes (`historical`, `broker`, `coordinator`, `overlord`, etc), as well as set up `tranquility` too.

It works as expected and the data is being pushed correctly as well.

However, whenever I exit a process (`Ctrl + C`), or if I close my session in the terminal, the processes naturally stop as well.

Is there an out-of-the-box tool or service provided by Druid itself that would all the running processes to persist even when the terminal is closed?

I'm aware I can use `tmux` (or maybe `upstart`) to achieve the same, but that feels more of a last resort approach, which can be used to continue almost any process running on Linux in general.

What I'm looking for is something that Druid itself provides (like `pm2` for node.js or `wsgi` for django).

I tried googling but didn't really get anything significant.

Answer (score 0):

At [my work](https://imply.io/) we use [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/) to set up long-running Druid services. We're running on Ubuntu, where there is a package for it that you can get through apt-get.